# Dynamically changing favicon in react.js

Tags: reactjs

So I am currently working on a website in react, and I am trying to change the favicon dynamically.

I had found a snippet of code which I tried to adapt in order to make it work but clearly I'm still missing something. My website does not break but there are no changes.

Here is my code:

```
    import Logo from './Images/logo.png';



    function App() {
    
      //need help
      useEffect((url) =>{
    
      let link = document.queryCommandValue("link[rel~={Logo}]");
      if(!link){
        link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'icon';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
      }
      link.href = url;
    
    },[]); 
  return (
    <div className="App">
```

Comment: What is `queryCommandValue` where did you find it?

Comment: I think React Helmet might help you with that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it using React's `useEffect` hook and some JavaScript. Usually, you would define your `useEffect` in your page components, so when your page is rendered, the effect triggers which updates the favicon.

```
const Page1 = (props) => {
  // effect to update favicon
  useEffect(() => {
    let link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
    if (!link) {
      link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'icon';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
    link.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Page1</div>
  );
}
```

[Here's more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically) on how to change favicon dynamically with just JavaScript

Comment: Are you setting it like `link.href = {logo}` or `link.href = logo`?