# Changing website favicon depending on the url

Tags: reactjs, typescript, title, favicon

I have a client who would like our web application branded according to its url. They'd like to change the favicon of the page to be the logo of the private label and same with the title, but I'm unable to find any code or any examples of how to do this. Has anybody successfully done this before?

I'm picturing having a dozen icons in a folder, and the reference to which favicon.ico file to use is just generated dynamically along with the HTML page. Thoughts?

PS: we run our web app with React.js, TS, etc.

I have tried on the index.html page of our web application but this doesn't apply to a specific url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Comment: Unfortunately not... I have tried the different solutions :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible using different methods. One could be using UseEffect on pages where you need the other favicon, here is how you can do it:

```
const somePage = (props) => {
 //now this useEffect does the job for you
  useEffect(() => {
    let link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
    if (!link) {
      link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'icon';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
    link.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>somePage</div>
  );
}
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72505283/dynamically-changing-favicon-in-react-js) as well if it is not all clear to you.
As for the title you can do the same, or you can make the custom hook for it:

```
export function usePageTitle(title: string) {
  const documentDefined = typeof document !== 'undefined';
  const originalTitle = useRef(documentDefined ? document.title : null);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!documentDefined) return;

    if (document.title !== title) document.title = title;

    return () => {
      //@ts-ignore
      document.title = originalTitle.current;
    };
  }, []);
}
```

This is not hard to do and it is not heavy on the user's machine because it is just a simple HTML DOM Document Object manipulation. And you can make hooks for both of these things, or you can use it as simple useEffect in every component where you need it as a first example for favicon ico.

Comment: Thanks Cvijan! If I understand you correctly, the first code snippet is for the app.tsx as for the title, where should it be?
Another question, where can I define the text for the title?

Comment: First code can be put at the top of any functional component that represents your page where you want your favicon to be changed. Because that component gets rendered only when you route the client to that page, thus that useEffect gets triggered there only once because its dependency array is empty `[]` so it fires only when a component renders the first time. Basically use it in the page component.
As for the title, you can use it as the hook, and call it `usePageTitle('some title I want to show').

Comment: If you do not know how to make your's custom hook you can install it as npm package ,[this is the link to package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-page-title-updater).
Also [here](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) is how to make your custom hook and what it is.